# JAVA GET response for HTTP POST Request

Tags: java, android, http, post, response

How to get the status code or something better to know if an message was sent? 
I already do this, but off course it don't work.

```
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString()));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();

            Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "showOnScreenMessage", "Message sent! ");
            Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "showOnScreenMessage", "Status : " + status );

            // if response == 201 , the message has be received, Set True to acknowledgment_message 
            if ( status == "201"){
                Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "showOnScreenMessage", "Message received! ");


            }else{
                // Do nothing already false
                Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "showOnScreenMessage", "Message not received! ");
            }
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: `if ( status == "201"){` doesn't seem correct. Take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String compare as it's say above.

```
status.equals("201")
```

Or you can use :

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK
```

All status [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
status == "201"
```

to:

```
status.equals("201")
```