# Android post to html

Tags: java, android, apache, post

I use this code in my app to post:

```
          public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

my problem is that when I do 10 posts some time its slow and some times it's not recive answer from the server.
Their is a way to do a manager for the posts or some way to do it fater and to make sure that after this code run I know that it dose all it's needs to recive answer from the server?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `AsyncTask` for communicating with server

Comment: How can I do post with AsyncTask and what is the benefits?

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/what-is-asynctask-in-android/

Comment: I understand this but how this make sure that I receive answer from the server?

Comment: You need to check the response. Return true or false from the server or check the http response it self for 201. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486270/java-get-response-for-http-post-request